# MySQL: Any suggestions to improve best match Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, range

For a project I am working on I have to scan a key for best match. Only these scan are causing a lot of load on our test system. Any body an idea how I can improve this? We already tried temporary tables and Cursors.

An example of the code we are using:

```
SET keyLength = (LENGTH(key)-1);
WHILE keyLength >=1 DO
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO resultCount FROM keytable
    WHERE I ScreeningKey = (SELECT SUBSTRING(key)-,1,keyLength));
    IF (0 < resultCount) THEN
        SELECT ScreeningKey INTO bestMatchScreeningKey FROM keytable 
        WHERE AND ScreeningKey = (SELECT SUBSTRING(key)-,1,keyLength));

        /*go to step4*/
        LEAVE Step4;
    END IF;
    SET keyLength = keyLength-1;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: What exactly does this code try to do? And is this the whole procedure or just a part?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `SELECT COUNT(*)` just use `IF EXISTS`. The `IF EXISTS` can stop scanning as soon as it finds a match, while `COUNT(*)` needs to go through the entire table to tally up that count.

So, you would end up with something like: (I don't use much MySQL, so I'm not sure on the syntax and I copy-pasted your syntax which doesn't look quite right to me...)

```
SET keyLength = (LENGTH(key)-1);
WHILE keyLength >=1 DO
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM keytable
               WHERE I ScreeningKey = (SELECT SUBSTRING(key)-,1,keyLength))) THEN
        SELECT SUBSTRING(key)-,1,keyLength INTO bestMatchScreeningKey;

        /*go to step4*/
        LEAVE Step4;
    END IF;
    SET keyLength = keyLength-1;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: There is in TSQL, but MySQL may be different. Try `SET resultCount = SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS ( ... )`

Comment: There is certainly an `EXISTS` construct in MySQL, but I don't know if it can be used in an `IF` statement as I have it. You could easily rework it though to still avoid the COUNT(*). If anyone who has MySQL server handy (I only have it on my home machine) can confirm, then I can rework my answer if necessary. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ?

For every iteration where no data is found it jumps into the exception block (skipping the LEAVE) until a record is found.

This will save you doing 2 selects for each iteration.

Note I added a LIMIT 1 to stop the possibility of the select returning several rows.

```
SET keyLength = (LENGTH(key)-1);
WHILE keyLength >=1 DO
BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTRING(key)-,1,keyLength INTO bestMatchScreeningKey LIMIT 1;
    LEAVE Step4;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        NULL;
    WHEN others THEN
        RAISE;
END;
    SET keyLength = keyLength-1;
END WHILE;
```